# throw new error(errors.map((error) => error.message).join('\n\n'));

Tags: apollo-server

throw new Error(errors.map((error) => error.message).join('\n\n'));
^

Error: The type of Mutation.signinUser(userSignin:) must be Input Type but got: UserSigninInput.
at assertValidSchema (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\graphql\type\validate.js:59:11)
at assertValidExecutionArguments (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:194:35)
at execute (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:113:3)
at generateSchemaHash (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\utils\schemaHash.js:15:44)
at ApolloServer.generateSchemaDerivedData (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:357:64)
at Object.schemaDerivedDataProvider (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:141:65)
at new SchemaManager (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\utils\schemaManager.js:21:44)
at new ApolloServerBase (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:139:32)
at new ApolloServer (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\apollo-server-express\dist\ApolloServer.js:13:1)
at new ApolloServer (E:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\apollo-server\dist\index.js:31:9)

Comment: Please provide more details and code to reproduce the error. Check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

**now i solve this error now i tell you how can solve this error* i had check my typedefs file and my mistake was `type UserInput` so now it is userinput not `type`
it is `input` write `input UserInput` after that solve error

Answer (score 0):

if you get this error in garphql you probably wrote extra data variables in your type please check all your create updates or delete things and remove unnecessary data then you must fix the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).